# grep with regex to match lines starting with exactly three lowercase letters

Tags: regex, unix, grep

So normally I have a pretty good handle on using grep with regular expressions but I'm hung up on this simple thing. I have the following text file named first-paragraph.txt (shown below) and I want to find all lines that start with exactly three lowercase characters '^[a-z]{3}' but I cannot seam to make it work.

```
It was the best of times,
it was the worst of times,
it was the age of wisdom,
it was the age of foolishness,
it was the epoch of belief,
it was the epoch of incredulity,
it was the season of Light,
it was the season of Darkness,
it was the spring of hope,
it was the winter of despair,
we had everything before us,
we had nothing before us,
we were all going direct to Heaven,
we were all going direct the other way--
in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of
its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for
evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.
```

And trying this gives me all lines starting with three or more lowercase characters but, I don't understand why I'm not only getting the one line that actually starts with three characters 'its ....'

```
$ grep '^[a-z]\{3\}' first-paragraph.txt 
its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for
evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.
$ grep '^[a-z]\{3\}$' first-paragraph.txt # no lines
$ grep '^([a-z])\{3\}' first-paragraph.txt # no lines
```

Comment: Do you need `grep '^[a-z]\{3\}\b' file` ([demo](https://ideone.com/0IiHcp))?

Comment: hmm ... I really need to use the bounding symbol? thats kinda odd but thanks

Comment: Wouldn't '^[a-z]\{3\}[^a-z]' do it?

Comment: @mevets It won't work with `hot` line (i.e. exactly three letters).

Comment: See my answer below, you are not forced to only use the word boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
grep '^[a-z]\{3\}\b' file # \b is a word boundary
```

See [this `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/0IiHcp).

Or, if your `grep` does not support the word boundary construct, you may use

```
grep -e '^[a-z]\{3\}$' -e '^[a-z]\{3\}[^[:alnum:]]' file
```

where the first pattern will match 3-letter only lines and the second one will only match those where the fourth char is a non-alphanumeric char.

See [this `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/eDP4AC).

You may replace `[^[:alnum:]]` with `[^[:alpha:]]` if you want to allow any char other than a letter to appear inside a "word" (i.e. if you want to get a match for `cat123`). Or, you may replace `[:alnum:]` with `[:space:]` to only signal the end of a word when it ends with a whitespace.